# Conditional Formatting formula not working (no effect)

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a sheet that formats every cell that meets a criterion (the letter `o`), based on another static cell (A1, which will only be `r`, `y` or `b`). I've looked around for how to do it and came up with this:

```
=if(or(and($A$1="r",address(row(),column())="o"),and($A$1="y",address(row(),column())="o")))
```

The syntax is correct but it's not doing anything. I expect all cells in range that are `o` to be formatted when I set A1 to either `r` or `y`, but neither cause any change. I've reviewed the formula several times and can't find what is preventing it from working.

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect all cells in range that are "o" to be formatted when I set A1 to either "r" or "y"

Please try clearing formatting from and selecting the appropriate range (say starting in C3) and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=and(or($A$1="r",$A$1="y"),C3="o")
```

Then select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Use delimiters appropriate for your locale.

Comment: [Here an example](https://imgur.com/s3mDlWA) with one rule and some boolean operators.